# In related Contacts list it shows account field instead of contact fields

Tags: deployment, page-layout, error, metadata, related-list

I am seeing some discrepancies with related list page layout deployment.
The columns are shown in Contact related list on custom object page layout changes when deployed to the instance.

Columns in the Contact-related list are:

- Name
- Account Name
- Description(custom field on Contact)

The metadata file also shows these columns but when this layout gets deployed to the environment the `Description` (custom field on Contact) is changed to `Account:Description` (custom field on Account). After deployment when I retrieve meta.xml file for page layout from the instance, it didn't show any "Description" field in that.

Contact Related List [image: Contact related List]

Meta.xml file which I have deployed
[image: Meta.xml file before deployment]

Meta.xml file retrieved after deployment
[image: meta.xml file after deployment]

Comment: Is the custom field on the Contact deployed in that environment?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes, It's deployed.